# Having trouble launching Google Chrome through Selenium RC server on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm running Selenium RC server 2.0b3 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I installed Google Chrome and am trying to run some tests against it.  I'm able to run tests against Firefox just fine.  However, when I run my test against the Selenium server, it just hangs and then times out.  This is all the server log reports (notice the null session):

```
16:14:16.810 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*googlechrome, http://mydomain.com, ] on session null
16:14:16.810 INFO - creating new remote session
16:14:16.811 INFO - Allocated session 6913c9613c554db798e109eadefd43da for http://mydomain.com, launching...
16:14:16.811 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...
16:19:44.776 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:521)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:374)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:785)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:146)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
16:19:44.777 INFO - Killing Google Chrome...
16:19:44.777 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
```

I am starting Selenium as a service on system startup, like so ...

```
start() {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting selenium-server server: "
    /usr/bin/Xvfb :15 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 &
    export DISPLAY=localhost:15.0
    su selenium -c 'java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar -userExtensions /opt/selenium/user-extensions.js > /var/log/se_rc_server.log 2>&1 &'
    PID=$!
    ### Create the lock file ###
    echo $PID > /var/run/selenium-server.pid
    echo
```

Any ideas how I can eliminate the Google Chrome null sessions and get my tests to run?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Could you share your test code? The one that connects to the selenium server?

Comment: Do you have `google-chrome` at `/usr/bin/google-chrome` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into Chrome's security restrictions.  You need to set the "mode" value to "disableSecurity" in your BrowserConfigurationOptions to disable them.

Comment: How do you do this?  I've tried creating a "/usr/bin/google-chrome" file with the contents "chromium-browser --disable-web-security", but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what language you're using, but in Java you'd call the `set()` method.  Here are the JavaDocs (adapting to whatever language you are using should be straightforward): http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/BrowserConfigurationOptions.html

Comment: Is what you're suggesting the equivalent of starting Google Chrome / Chromium with the "--disable-web-security" option?  I'm using the HttpCommandProcessor class to send commands (http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/HttpCommandProcessor.html) and it doesn't include an option for BrowserConfiguration, so I'm looking for another way to do the same thing.